# gnumake .RECIPEPREFIX problem

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to use the special variable .RECIPEPREFIX in order to avoid the hard to see tabs, but it does not seem to work. My simple test makefile is:

```
    .RECIPEPREFIX = +

    all:
    + @echo OK
```

but I get the message:

```
xxx:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Which version of gnu make are you using? 3.81?

The .RECIPEPREFIX is only supported since 3.82.  I've tested out your sample on 3.82 and it works.

http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/make/NEWS?revision=2.109&root=make&view=markup

> - New special variable: .RECIPEPREFIX allows you to reset the recipe
>     introduction character from the default (TAB) to something else.  The
>     first character of this variable value is the new recipe introduction
>     character.  If the variable is set to the empty string, TAB is used again.
>     It can be set and reset at will; recipes will use the value active when
>     they were first parsed.  To detect this feature check the value of
>     $(.RECIPEPREFIX).

Comment: That's it! My make is version 3.81. Thanks!